# Bulk insert CSV into SQL Server Azure - referenced external data source not found

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to bulk insert a csv I have in a storage container into a table so that I can refresh this query and do it automatically.

However, it says my data source doesn't exists:

> Referenced external data source "storagename" not found

Blob public access is enabled so I shouldn't need a credential.

- My storage account name is `storagename`
- My container name is `headcountdata`
- My csv name is `Kamsa_Data.csv`

This is my code:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [FPA_Headcount].[dbo].[kamsa_employees]

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE storagename -- this is the name of the storage account
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/headcountdata'
    )

BULK INSERT [FPA_Headcount].[dbo].[kamsa_employees]
FROM 'Kamsa_Data.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'storagename', -- this is the name of the storage account
FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

Should the data source be the name of the container or storage account? Either doesn't work anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

SQL - OPENROWSET

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'your_name.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureFile',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='invoices.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureFile'
   ) AS DataFile;
```

Using BULK INSERT, use the container and file description:
SQL

```
BULK INSERT Colors2
FROM 'your_name.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzure',
      FORMAT = 'CSV');
```